# How can i make several labels clickable in a shortcut?

Tags: swift, label, uitapgesturerecognizer, clickable

in my code i have a tableView and several labels.. 
I want that the when the user click on cell and after that click on one of the labels, the text in the label will be same as the text in the row that be clicked.

Q1. How can i enable all labels to be clickable and connect to one function that will point on the specific label each time the user click on it?

Q2. I tried to make the same gesture to all labels with UITapGestureRecognizer.. apparently this gesture refers only to the last label (Lbl4 down here in code example).. it means that the text in Lbl1 in my func change only by clicking on Lbl4..  why is that? and how can i change it that it will refers to all labels?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(ViewController.lblTapped)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    Lbl1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    Lbl2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    Lbl3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    Lbl4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

func lblTapped(){
    Lbl1.text = self.currentPlayerChooseInRow

}
```

Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand UITableView object. UITableView is an array of cells, ok? Then, you need use some methods associated to UITableView like numberOfRowsInSection (where app knows the number of cells) and cellForRowAtIndexPath (where app knows cell will be)

About your questions, i recomend you to use outlets to connect labels, buttons, objects to the controller (try to not use gestures if it is not necessary)

Finally, object cells are programmed into cell. If you have a complex cell, you will need a custom cell controller.

Comment: first thanks for your comment. my tableview works fine and  i have outlet that connect to all labels.. my questions is about clickable and enable action for all labels that will be excute by one method/func  if it possible and how to achieve that..

Comment: ok, well. you need a controller cell into yout table and link your label with your outlet in your UITableViewCell controller. you don't need create label1, label2, .... in viewdidload from your uitableviewcontroller.